# JavaFX beans vs. properties -- why both?

Tags: java, clojure, javafx, javabeans

I'm looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleObjectProperty.html and I'm somewhat confused.

I can create a `SimpleObjectProperty` using the third constructor,

```
SimpleObjectProperty(Object bean, String name, T initialValue)
```

in Clojure as follows: `(def sop (SimpleObjectProperty. 5 "mysop" 6))`

This creates a `SimpleObjectProperty` with Bean value = 5 (of type `java.lang.Long`) and non-Bean value = 6, also of type `(java.lang.Long)`.

Why have two different "values"?  What is the purpose of a "Bean" in this case?  Which one should I use?  I'm trying to encapsulate a generic Clojure Object on which I can set Listeners, so I'm thinking it's either this, or `ObjectPropertyBase` which is one up the hierarchy and also directly instantiable.

I've slowly been absorbing Java as necessary to understand how to use JavaFX in Clojure, but this one is confusing.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "bean" is the object for which the `ObjectProperty` is a property (in other words, it is the Java object that "owns" the ObjectProperty). See the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyProperty.html#getBean--).

This can be useful if you have a change listener registered with properties from multiple sources, and want to be able to distinguish the object whose state has changed:

```
ChangeListener<Object> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    ObjectProperty objProp = (ObjectProperty) observable ;
    Object bean = objProp.getBean();
    // do something....
};

someProperty.addListener(listener);
someOtherProperty.addListener(listener);
```

Typically you would use the bean reference as follows:

```
public class Person {
    // parameters are "owning bean" (i.e. this person), property name, and initial value:
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "Fred");
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }
    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so the first argument is essentially the parent of the bean, in terms of encapsulation.

Comment: @Sonicsmooth most of the time, you just don't care about the "bean" and "name" and can just use `new SimpleObjectProperty(initialValue)`.  Note that in the supposedly useful case @James_D mentions, you will need to do two casts to actually do anything useful. I have yet to see an actually useful use of the bean and name attributes, other than showing them in debugging output.

Comment: @TomasMikula Agreed: I much prefer not sharing listeners in general. I did say "*can be* useful" ;).